# SharePoint search index location as network drive file space

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

We are supporting SharePoint 2013 onpremises with Search topology running specifically on two servers with 20 Million items in index location.

The search index space is occupying 300 GB space in each server as we have index component running on two search servers.

Due to the disk space capacity issues, can we choose index location as common network drive file space for both search servers?

Is this kind of index location supported in SharePoint search topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a supported configuration. Each server in the topology must have it's own instance of the index and the location must be common to both servers. A better option is to add another disk to each machine with the same drive letter. Update your topology to indicate the path to the new Index Location and let the Index Component move the index for you.

I should also add that SharePoint 2013 index limit is 10M items per index partition. For 20M items you should either create a second (or third) partition (or upgrade to 2016/2019) with support 20M items per index partition.